# Is there any STAC catalog available for Sentinel-2 data on Google Cloud?

Tags: sentinel-2, google-cloud, stac

We are looking for a fast and optimum way of discovering and downloading Sentinel-2 data from Google Cloud using Python.

We have tried using index data in BigQuery and it works. However, we have also come across Python packages (such as: sat-search https://github.com/sat-utils/sat-search) for searching and downloading publicly available satellite imagery using STAC compliant APIs that we would prefer to use, but we haven't found any STAC catalogs for Sentinel-2 datasets on Google Cloud or any STAC API endpoints for the same. Is anyone aware of any STAC catalogs for datasets on Google Cloud or if there are plans to have them in the near future?

AWS has both: Sentinel-2-L1C and L2A datasets, and has recently released these in COG (Cloud Optimized Geotiff) format which seems to be better suited to large-scale and distributed computing. Does anyone know if similar datasets will be available on Google Cloud as well?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stacindex.org/catalogs?access=public&type=api) you can find a list of public STAC Catalogs and there is the Google Earth Engine STAC Catalog [here](https://stacindex.org/catalogs/google-earth-engine-openeo#/).